# Dynamically access variables in external session?

Tags: dynamic, external-calls, python

I tried to get a value from a python session to show up in a dynamic cell:

[image]

First run:

```
Dynamic[ExternalEvaluate[CurrentValue[
   EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "ExternalSessions", "Python"}], "i"], 
 UpdateInterval -> 0]
```

Then run this in a python code cell:

```
global i
import time 
for x in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    i = x
    print(x)
```

But it doesn't seem to work, is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 5):

I believe this general approach is destined to fail. You are asking Mathematica to interrupt python, get a value from it, then allow python to continue running. I am very skeptical that such a thing is possible.

A more realistic approach is to have python send back any values you wish to be kept current on. Here is a simple implementation

```
command = {"import time", "for x in range (10):", "    time.sleep(1)","    i = x", "    print(x)", ""};
process = StartProcess[{"python", "-i"}]
Dynamic[Refresh[Block[{temp},
    temp = ReadString[process, EndOfBuffer];
    If[temp != "", x = ToExpression[temp]];
    ], UpdateInterval -> 0.1]];
Dynamic[x]
WriteLine[process, #] & /@ command;
```

The basic idea here is to use a *Process* instead of an *ExternalSession*. From the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StartProcess.html) on `StartProcess`:

> StartProcess can be used to interact with processes while they are running or to run "background tasks" without blocking the Wolfram Engine.
>
> StartProcess returns immediately and does not wait for the started process to complete. Use RunProcess to wait for a process to complete.
>
> The Wolfram Engine can communicate with a subprocess represented by a ProcessObject with functions like WriteLine, WriteString, BinaryWrite, ReadLine, ReadString, and BinaryRead.

This allows us to easily read in the outputs of a python program while it's running. Print statements are written to a `Stream` which can be accessed in real time. Theoretically one may be able to accomplish similar functionality with an `ExternalSession` by redirecting `$Output` to its own `Stream` and then reading from that, but it wasn't designed to be used this way and would be much uglier if it worked at all.

I am using the `ReadString` function with `EndOfBuffer` to make it read what's available immediately and only storing the value if it's not `""` which is what's returned when the Buffer is empty. This in effect gives `x` the value of the last character printed by python. If you want to keep track of more complicated stuff, a more complicated print/read scheme is likely in order.

The `command` list looks a bit clunky, but it would be simple and elegant to write a python script, read it into a list then execute as shown above.

[image: AnimationOfCodeWorking]