# How to monitor progress with external language code?

Tags: dynamic, python, external-calls, external-language-cell

I'm trying to figure out how to get **tqdm** (a python progress monitoring tool) to work with `ExternalEvaluate` and `"ExternalLanguage"` cells. I probably use [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) (along with its multithreading counterpart [atpbar](https://github.com/alphatwirl/atpbar/releases)) just about every day!

Here's what it looks like in the console or ipython:

[image]

It works nicely in Jupyter notebooks as well:

[image]

**What I've Tried:**

Assuming tqdm is installed, this is the current behavior in external code cells:

```
(* external cell code *)
from tqdm import tqdm; pbar = tqdm(total=3)
for i in range(3):
    pbar.write(f'{i} Print works but no bar :(')
    pbar.update(1)
```

[image]

The write method works, but there is no cell printed for the progress bar. `ExternalEvaluate` has the same problem:

[image]

I realize this is might require a sophisticated hack, but it would make using Python in MMA much more practical for many users.

**Related:**

- [Dynamically access variables in external session?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179857/dynamically-access-variables-in-external-session)

Comment: Any ideas please?